# Merge the "bug" and "bug-report" tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

On this meta site there are three questions tagged with [bug-report](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-report); two of those questions are also tagged with [bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), and one is only tagged with [bug-report](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-report).

As there are 40 questions tagged [bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), this tag should probably be kept, and the other tag should be merged with it (and made a synonym).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These have now been merged and a synonym created.